# Need help handling error message: Ivalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I try to compile my code where ann is an annotation, coordinate is a 2d coordinate, and latit is a float

```
ann.coordinate.latitude = latit;
```

I get an error message saying Ivalue required as left operand of assignment. What does this error mean and why is it showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing up because you're being confused by the two distinct uses of dot notation. The first is `ann.coordinate`, where coordinate is a property of whatever object ann is. The second is `coordinate.latitude`, where coordinate is a struct and latitude is a field in the struct. Normally one can assign to a property, as in `ann.coordinate = aNewCoordinate`. And normally one can assign to a struct field, as in `coordinate.latitude = latit`. However, one cannot assign to a field of an anonymous struct returned from a property getter. This will become quite obvious if you remove the property dot notation, as you are then left with `[ann coordinate].latitude = latit`, which is clearly wrong. Semantically, you are asking the compiler to construct code that looks similar to

```
__typeof__(ann.coordinate) __tempCoordinate = ann.coordinate;
__tempCoordinate.latitude = latit;
ann.coordinate = __tempCoordinate;
```

but this is far out of the scope of the dot syntax and the compiler refuses to generate this code (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 1):

It means that when you do ann.coordinate.latitude you are actually trying to assign something to a getter. latitude RETURNS a value and you cannot assign something to it. You have to create a new coordinate and assign it to ann.